# banach algebra and modular left ideal

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

I'm solving conway's functional analysis.

> Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a Banach algebra but do not assume it has an identity. If $I$ is a left ideal of $\mathcal{A}$, we say $I$ is modular left ideal if there is $u$ in $\mathcal{A}$ s.t. $\mathcal{A}(1-u) \equiv \{a-au:a\in\mathcal{A}\} \subset I$.$\qquad$(a) if $u$ is right modular unit(i.e. $u \equiv au \mod I $) for left ideal and $u \in I$, then $I = \mathcal{A}$

I solved this one because for $a \in \mathcal{A}$, $a = au + i$ for $i \in I$ and using $I$ is left ideal.

> (b)  Maximal modular left ideals are maximal left ideals.

I tried this one that assuming $M$ is Maximal modular left ideal. Then $M + Au$ is also modular left ideal so $M= M+Au$ or $A = M+Au$, so,  in former case $M= Au$, and second case, $M = \{a-au:a\in\mathcal{A}\}$, but I cannot proceed to these two are maximal left ideals.

> (c) If $I$ is proper modular left idea, then $I$ is contained in a maximal left ideal.

I solved this one via Zorn's lemma

> (d) If $I$ is a proper modular left ideal and $u$ is a modular right unit for $I$, then $||u-x||\geq 1$for all $x$ in $I$ and $cl I$ is a proper modular left ideal.

I think this is very similar to the lemma that if $||1-a||<1$ then it has inverses. In my guess, $u$ is similar to identity in $A/I$(can I define this one? $I$ is not ideal(but left ideal)) so it can be solved with (a), but no idea because it is only one-side identity.

> (e) Every maximal modular left ideal of $\mathcal{A}$ is closed

(e) is direct result of (d).

I need help of problem (b) and (d). Since I only studied [Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra] so my background of Algebra is too weak. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(b). Maximal modular left-ideals of the Banach algebra $\mathcal{A}$ are maximal left-ideals.

*Proof:* Let $J$ be a modular left-ideal maximal among the left-modular ones.
In particular, we have an element $e \in \mathcal{A}$ with $\mathcal{A}(1-e) \subset J$. Say $J \subset T$ where $T$ is another left-ideal.

Then, for all $x \in \mathcal{A}$, we have $x - xe \in J$ by definition. Thus also $x-xe \in T$. Hence $\mathcal{A}(1-e) \subset T$ showing that $T$ is a modular left-ideal.

By maximality, $J = T$ or $T = \mathcal{A}$. $\square$

(d). If $J$ is a proper modular left-ideal and $e \in \mathcal{A}$ has the property: $\mathcal{A}(1-e) \subset J$, then $J$ does not intersect the $1$ ball around $e$.

*Proof:* Say, for sake of contradiction, that there exists $x \in J$ with $\|e - x\| < 1$. The we have the convergent series
\begin{equation}
z = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty (e-x)^n \in \mathcal{A}.
\end{equation}
It is straightforward to check the identity
\begin{equation}
z + (e-x) - z(e-x) = 0
\end{equation}
whence
\begin{equation}
 e = x - z + ze - zx = (x-zx) - (z - ze).
\end{equation}
This last term belongs to the left-ideal $J$ since $x \in J$ and by the defining property of $e$.

Thus $e \in J$ which shows that $J = \mathcal{A}$ which is a contradiction. $\square$